# Handling private write methods on singleton EJBs

Tags: java, locking, singleton, ejb

I have a singleton EJB whose business methods are all `@Lock(READ)`. However, on special ocassions, some of them call a private method that persists stuff on a database. What's the best way to handle this situation? Should I:

- Use `@Lock(WRITE)` for that private method even though it's not a business method? If so, is this a reliable behaviour?
- Do the synchronization on the private method myself? If so, is it safe to synchronize over the `EntityManager`?
- Do something completely different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only partially answers your question, but here goes.

You could put the private methods in a "private" businness interface and call them via the container like this:

**TestEJB.java**:

```
@Stateless
public class TestEJB implements PrivateIface, PublicIface {
    SessionContext ctx;

    public void doBusiness() {
        PrivateIface businessObject = ctx.getBusinessObject(PrivateIface.class);
        businessObject.doPrivateBusinness();
    }
    @SomeContainerAnnotation
    public void doPrivateBusinness() {

    }
}

@Local
interface PrivateIface {
    void doPrivateBusinness();
}
```

**PublicIface.java**:

```
@Local
public interface PublicIface {
    void doBusiness();
}
```